# When is it appropriate to use　ごくろうさま?

Tags: usage, nuances, set-phrases, greetings

I've seen お疲れさま and ご[苦労]{くろう}さま used to say "Thank you" after some had done work of some type. After reading the お疲れさま thread, I realize that the two are not interchangeable. So when do you use ご[苦労]{くろう}さま?

[When is it appropriate to use otsukaresama?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-%E3%81%8A%E7%96%B2%E3%82%8C%E6%A7%98-otsukaresama)

Comment: It might be fun to also compare "お疲れ～!" and "ご苦労。" :D

Comment: @Chocolate true, true, that would be interesting; people my age always seem to end up using お疲れ〜 with me, and older people always seem to use ご苦労 with me, haha...

Comment: @Chocolate: Feel free to. However, please make it an answer not a comment :)

Comment: @summea: See above :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When and to whom should I use the expression ご苦労様 (gokurousama)?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/when-and-to-whom-should-i-use-the-expression-%e3%81%94%e8%8b%a6%e5%8a%b4%e6%a7%98-gokurousama)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*First, a note:* because there is a ご at the beginning of ごくろうさま, that お〜 is actually not there. :)

I've most often heard ご苦労様{くろうさま} used by people older than myself, when I have done something for the person (or in some way have helped the person,) using that phrase.  (Besides age, this could also happen in a business situation, where a senior worker is speaking to a junior worker.)

For reference, more information can be found in the following article: [御苦労様](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tinuyama/20060727).

Comment: The first link no longer works, but now connects to something spammy/inappropriate.

Comment: @JacobMaibach Thank you for letting me know, Jacob! I've removed that link from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand it, it is sort of a subsection of when you might say `お疲れ様でした`, for when people are "just doing their job" so to speak. Like if a firefighter gets a cat from out of a tree, or you're leaving your job site and are talking to your co-workers. It seems to me that this is said to police officers a lot.

Comment: Can someone explain why I'm wrong/got downvoted please?